# How to enable fully working HTTPS for .NET Core WebApp on Debian with nginx?

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, .net-core, debian

I'd want to encrypt traffic to my webapp via HTTPS but I'm struggling with it on Debian

Of course there's guide at Microsoft's site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

but... is not that just redirection?

```
This document shows how to:

Require HTTPS for all requests.
Redirect all HTTP requests to HTT
```

How can I create those .pfx files or whatever else I need to add HTTPs to my webapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use `nginx` as reverse proxy for your web application. In this case you won't need to modify your app code, you will be able to modify your `HTTPS` settings without any modifications in web app. Steps:

1) Setup your website, for example it will use port `5000`

2) Install `nginx` and create basic config like this one:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream app_servers {
        server web:5000;
    }

    server {
        server_name your_server_name_here.com;
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

Read more about configuration [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html).

3) Use [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) for obtaining free `HTTPS` certificates via [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianstretch-nginx). It will do all job for working with certs and will modify your `nginx` config automatically

Also I suggest to use [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) - it will help you to separate code and proxy better.